# removing images elements using DOM method

Tags: javascript, dom

Can anybody explain why remove() method does not work as I expected. I want remove all img elements from the document. 
Loop through document and remove all images, that is what I want but this removes only 2 images,why?
Here is the code [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/vixaxocige/1/edit?html,js,output)

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="pic">
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50/animals" alt="pic">
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50/city" alt="pic">
```

**JS**

```
var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); // HTMLCollection

for(var i=0; i<imgElements.length; i++) {
  var img = imgElements[i];
  img.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things that worry me about that code:

1. `remove` is a relatively new DOM method which isn't well-supported. For better support, use `img.parentNode.removeChild(img);`
2. `getElementsByTagName` returns a **live** `NodeList`, and so when you remove the elements from the beginning of the list, all the others shift up. So if the list has 5 entries, and you remove the `i=0` element, all the others move and now there's a *new* `i=0` element (and the length is `4`). Your loop will move on to `i=1` and so the element at `i=0` (which used to be at `i=1`) won't get processed.

   For a non-live `NodeList`, use `querySelectorAll('tagname')` (or just loop through the list backward, removing from the end). Or use `Array.prototype.slice` to convert the `NodeList` into an array.

   `querySelectorAll` is supported by all modern browsers, and also by IE8.

Here's an example using `querySelectorAll`:

```
var imgElements = document.querySelectorAll("img"); // HTMLCollection
for(var i=0; i<imgElements.length; i++) {
  var img = imgElements[i];
  img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
}
```

Or just counting backward:

```
var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); // HTMLCollection
for(var i=imgElements.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
  var img = imgElements[i];
  img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
}
```

Or using `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
var imgElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"));
for(var i=0; i<imgElements.length; i++) {
  var img = imgElements[i];
  img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
}
```

Comment: @StefanHaustein: Indeed. :-) (I thought I'd put that in the original, but in any case, it's there now in the version with examples.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder now everything is crystally clear, I totally forget that getElementsByTagName returns live html collection, thanks bro.